# android move image view in an arc

Tags: android, android-animation

We would like to use sin & cos to move an imageview in two arc's where the shape is like the outside perimeter of a NFL football. Our less than elegant code is below. It works but when we try to solve this animation with sin and cos the first problem is the coordinate system think the points 0,0 is the top left corner of the screen and moves the imageview and starts moving it off the screen. We have tried to overcome this by various methods none of which work. We know the start and stop X and Y points but do not know the radius of the circle.
So question one is how to get the imageview in the correct position?
Question two is how to move the imageview across the top arc and then back to the start position along the bottom arc. 
We used Android in the question because this is not a math or JavaFX question 
please understand we know the math this is about implementing it in Android with sin and cos.
This link is close [cos & sin use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141208/how-to-draw-circles-in-an-arc)

and here is our working code

```
    public void startGAME(View view){

    earth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    earth.setX(60);
    earth.setY(520);
    // Create and Start the timer.
    timer = new Timer();
    handler = new Handler();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    orbitEARTH();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}

public void orbitEARTH(){

    if(earth.getX() == 828){
        number = 2;
    }
    if(earth.getX() == 1884){
        number = 3;
    }
    if(earth.getX() == 914){
        number = 4;
    }
    if(earth.getX() == 41){
        earth.setX(60);
        earth.setY(520);
        number = 1;
    }

    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            xPos = (int) (earth.getX()+96);
            yPos = (int) (earth.getY()-30);
            earth.setX(xPos);
            earth.setY(yPos);
            System.out.println("##### 1 xPos"+xPos+" yPos "+yPos);
            break;
        case 2:
            xPos = (int) (earth.getX()+96);
            yPos = (int) (earth.getY()+30);
            earth.setX(xPos);
            earth.setY(yPos);
            System.out.println("##### 2 xPos"+xPos+" yPos "+yPos);
            break;
        case 3:
            xPos = (int) (earth.getX()-97);
            yPos = (int) (earth.getY()+30);
            earth.setX(xPos);
            earth.setY(yPos);
            System.out.println("##### 3 xPos"+xPos+" yPos "+yPos);
            break;

        case 4:
            xPos = (int) (earth.getX()-97);
            yPos = (int) (earth.getY()-30);
            earth.setX(xPos);
            earth.setY(yPos);
            System.out.println("##### 4 xPos"+xPos+" yPos "+yPos);
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all reality I am not sure your code is NOT that elegant. It has taken a lot more thought and work to use sin and cos to move the earth in its orbit. That said if any one tries this code so many of the variables are dependent on one another it is less than ideal what I am about to post. But it does answer the question 
so here is I might suggest following this link to grasp the subject

[Math](https://math.libretexts.org/Core/Precalculus/Chapter_5%3A_Trigonometric_Functions_of_Angles/5.3_Points_on_Circles_using_Sine_and_Cosine)

```
    public void startGAME(View view){

    earth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    earth.setX(60);
    earth.setY(520);
    // Create and Start the timer.
    timer = new Timer();
    handler = new Handler();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    newORBIT();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 500);
}

public void newORBIT(){
    newTheta = newTheta + 0.009;
    radius = 10;
    newDeltaX = radius*Math.cos(newTheta);
    newDeltaY = radius*Math.sin(newTheta);
    earth.setRotation(ANGLE += 7.5f);
    ANGLE = earth.getRotation();
    System.out.println("############# Angle "+ANGLE);
    if(ANGLE < 82.5) {
        X = (float) newDeltaX + 60;
        Y = (float) newDeltaY - 18.75f;
    }

    if(ANGLE > 82.5){
        X = (float) newDeltaX + 60;
        Y = (float) newDeltaY + 18.75f;
    }
    if(ANGLE > 196){
        X = (float) newDeltaX - 60;
        Y = (float) newDeltaY + 18.75f;
    }
    if(ANGLE > 330){
        X = (float) newDeltaX - 60;
        Y = (float) newDeltaY - 18.75f;
    }
    if(ANGLE > 457){
        ANGLE = 0;
        newTheta = 0;
        newDeltaX = 0.0f;
        newDeltaY = 0.0f;
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        earth.setRotation(0);
        earth.setX(60);
        earth.setY(520);
    }
    earth.setX(earth.getX()+X);
    earth.setY(earth.getY()+Y);

}
```

Comment: how did you decide on these values     newTheta = newTheta + 0.009;
    radius = 10;

Comment: @James_Duh Way too much trial and mostly error The hard part of this is the break points you used X coordinate the angles I used work but are too dependent on other values RISE and RUN are less than perfect but you can play with the code enjoy